# How to implement a comment structure like stackoverflow

Tags: html, css

**Here is the scenario:** I want exactly something like stackoverflow's comments. A table contained 3 `<td>`. one for the number of votes, one for shapes (vote up and flag), one for text of comment. So each `<td>` has its own property:

- **VN** *(Votes Number)*: If the number not exist, then `width = 0;`, also the with of this cell should be dynamic. *(for every-digit number)*
- **S** *(Shapes)*: This cell has fixed width, it should be noted that the `visibility` of its shapes is `hidden` in first and they will be show on hover of `<tr>`, then the width of this cell always should be assigned.
- **CT** *(Comment Text)*: The width of this cell should be all the remaining width. It should be `word-wrap: break-word;`.

---

### The structure:

```
+--+-+---------------------------------------------------+
|VN|S|CT                                                 |
+--+-+---------------------------------------------------+
```

**example1:**

```
+-+-+---------------------------------------------------+
|4|^|this comment is a test...!                         |
+-+-+---------------------------------------------------+
```

**example2:**

```
+-+------------------------------------------------------+
|^|this comment has not any voteup ...!                  |
+-+------------------------------------------------------+
```

**example3:**

```
+---+-+---------------------------------------------------+
|123|^|the width of number of vote up cell should be      |
|   | |changeable and it should be noted that this cell is|
|   | |break-word.                                        |
+---+-+---------------------------------------------------+
```

---

**Here is my try:** But it does not work correctly.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td class="VN">4</td>
         <td class="S">^</td>
         <td class="CT">this is a sample.</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container{
   width: 60%;
}

table{
   table-layout: fixed;
   width: 100%;
}

td{
   word-wrap: break-word;
   vertical-align: top;
}

.VN{
   width: auto;
}

.S{
   width: 10px;
}

.CT{
   width: 98%;
}
```

As I said, I don't know why my code does not work correctly *(It should be noted my container is responsive)*, How can I fix it ?
[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/rubhxdm1/7/) is a fiddle of what I did.

Comment: So, basically you want to hide the "VN" cell when it has no content. Why? And have you considered the effect of a list of items? It would mean elements with an empty "VN" cell have the other elements further to the left.

Comment: Why don't work? Provide a fiddle with the problem

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude please check out my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct but when user try to type "sssssssssssssssssssssssssssss" this will count as one word, so you need to add **Hyphenation** to your CSS code for recognition of long text since you have `word-break: break-word;`. https://jsfiddle.net/q7o6m2ka/2/

```
.CT {
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
        hyphens: auto;

    padding: 5px;
    width: 98%;
}
```

Comment: as I said in the previous comments, I don't want to use of `word-break`. because it breaks the words of the middle.

Comment: it work now, even if you remove the `word-break`, but you need to **Hyphenate**

Comment: very very good the answer of my question is just one word: *Hyphenate* :-) +1 vote up for you!!!

Answer (score 1):

With only this CSS your table works:

http://jsfiddle.net/1485tLf2/1

```
.container{
   width: 600px;
}

.S, .VN{
  width:  2%;
}
```

You don't need the other things. Tables fits automatically with content if you don't specifiy width. To avoid movements of elements and all comments will be symetric, only specify the small columns width. If the votes column needs more space, the table shrinks automatically to fix it without problems

## EDIT

In order to complete the code with your comments, here you are new css and fiddle:

```
.container{
   width: 60%;
}
td{
   vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid;
}
td.CT {
    word-break: break-all;
}
.S, .VN{
   width: 2%;
}
td:empty {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

See it working: https://jsfiddle.net/rubhxdm1/11/

Comment: please check out my update, container is not `600px`.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Put my code in your project and it works. See your fiddle edited by me:  https://jsfiddle.net/rubhxdm1/8/

Comment: yes, I think it works :-) ! thanks, just please put this in your code: `word-wrap: break-word;`. +1 vote up for you.

Comment: also when I remove vote number, It width is fixed !! I want if vote number was empty, then its width = 0;

Comment: You can't put width to zero when a td is empty, because in another rows `tr` the votes will not appear. Maybe you need to make it with divs and not tables. It's very strange and weird that you want to make, note that when you change a width of a column it propagates to all cells of this column. I don't recommend to make this crap in your code.

Comment: thanks buddy, but still when I have not any vote number, remains a waste of space.

Comment: Don't you read me? If you make with tables, it is the real and unique behaviour. Read all my comments. Stackoverflow's comments don't have this behaviour. All tables works identically: if you modify the width of a column, all cells in this column modifieds his width!!! You need to change tables to divs to solve your problem. IF you follow without reading or comprension with this, I go out of this topic. **The answer that you accepted as correct answer DON'T HAS THIS BEHAVIOUR.**

Comment: Really are you kidding me? https://jsfiddle.net/rubhxdm1/12/ Bah, I go out of this topic, you are wasting my time

Comment: look, your solution is great, I gave you +1 vote up, and sorry if you are thinking I wasting your time. and sorry if I upset you. I wish you all the best, and thanks again for your answer, good luck.

Comment: Sorry for said that you are wasting my time, only I am strangered with the solution as you marked as corrected, because is a dirty code to make what you need, it is better with divs.

Comment: yeah, maybe you are right, but I took a look at the structure of stackoverflow, it had done with table, and I copy the above structure (table) and that is fine for me.

Comment: Stackoverflow has ONE table for ALL comments. If comment hasn't votes, the space stay here, don't hide it. See how stackoverflow's comments works, it's totally different that you need

Comment: you are right, your code is more near to what I want, that code (table style) is not responsive. thanks, I mark your answer as main answer.

Comment: ok well, I don't want to use of `word-break: break-all;`, It breaks the work of the middle, I want to use of `word-wrap: break-word;` instead of it. how can implement it ?

Comment: The problem is when the text is a long word without spaces. However, you can change word break instead of word wrap in the same css class

Comment: yes exactly the problem is what you said, but with changing `word wrap` instead of `word break `, the problem does not solve, because the width or `CT` goes out of the range ... :-( also If I use of `table-layout: fixed;` for table, then the width of `VN` will be fixed (just for one-digit number). really I don't know what should I do ...

Comment: I think that for responsive purposes you can put word wrap without word break with a little piece of javascript that read the text of the comment and forbidden to the words whos string length is more than a number, for example no more than 40 characters each word. With this method, you can break long words (more than 40) with an space. Wit this you've got a responsive table layout without surprises.

Comment: I thought about your idea already (breaking long words). it is fine for every thing except when a user puts a url in the comment !

Answer (score 1):

here is a demo you can do it [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rubhxdm1/10/)

```
<div class="container">
   <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span>1</span></td>
                        <td><a>^</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <span>text of the comment</span>
             </div>
         </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This don't works as OP needs, but I think that is sleeping while he writing because it has no sense... https://jsfiddle.net/rubhxdm1/12/

Comment: There is a lot of space. However, it's fine, if you need it use it. https://jsfiddle.net/rubhxdm1/15/ See it working with your same problems. :P

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rubhxdm1/14/ fullfill the the three conditions as OP mentioned  .

Comment: @ManojDhiman are you serious? A new table every comment? This code is a really weird  code to show 3 cells... It is dirty, but op want it? I think this behaviour is better with divs, I tell him in my comments.

Comment: I just updated the code Op wants . why you are getting jealous ??

Comment: Sorry, but I still thinking a new table for each comment is dirty and very poor solution, in my opinion. However, I'm so sorry for my comments. Op can select the answer that he wants.